# gather function loses first column in original dataframe

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm trying to tidy a dataframe with `gather`, but am losing info in the process. Take the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(user = letters[1:10], score_1 = sample(1:20, 10), score_2 = sample(1:20, 10))

> head(df)
  user score_1 score_2
1    a       5       7
2    b      15       2
3    c      18      15
4    d       1      20
5    e      17      12
6    f       8      19
```

From here, I need to keep the identity of the user (first column), turn column names `score_1` and `score_2` into keys in a new "key" column, and convert all values of columns 2 and 3 into the values of my new "value" column. This is what I've tried:

```
gather(df, key = "user", value = "score", c(2,3))

      user score
1  score_1     5
2  score_1    15
3  score_1    18
4  score_1     1
5  score_1    17
6  score_1     8
7  score_1     2
8  score_1    20
9  score_1     9
10 score_1     3
11 score_2     7
12 score_2     2
13 score_2    15
14 score_2    20
15 score_2    12
16 score_2    19
17 score_2     8
18 score_2    13
19 score_2     4
20 score_2    18
```

This output is not satisfactory, because it loses the `user` column in the original dataframe. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is that the 'key' was specified as 'user'.  Here, the `key` is basically naming the column names created column in the 'long' format.  If we specify it as 'user' (which is already a column in the dataset), it would update by removing the existing  column

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df, key = "user1", value = "score", -user)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note from manual** `?gather`

> Development on `gather()` is complete, and for new code we recommend switching to `pivot_longer()`, which is easier to use, more featureful, and still under active development

**Here is the solution**

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(starts_with("score"), names_to = "score")

# # A tibble: 20 x 3
#    user  score   value
#    <fct> <chr>   <int>
#  1 a     score_1    10
#  2 a     score_2    19
#  3 b     score_1    13
#  4 b     score_2    18
#  5 c     score_1    11
#  6 c     score_2     8
#  7 d     score_1    15
#  8 d     score_2    13
#  9 e     score_1    14
# 10 e     score_2     3
# 11 f     score_1     8
# 12 f     score_2     5
# 13 g     score_1     2
# 14 g     score_2    12
# 15 h     score_1    17
# 16 h     score_2    10
# 17 i     score_1     3
# 18 i     score_2     1
# 19 j     score_1     1
# 20 j     score_2    16
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be using a variable name as the key. Try

```
gather(df, key = "usr", value = "score", score_1, score_2)
```